# ListView not displaying all items in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, landscape-portrait

I have an `Activity` that fits the screen size in portrait mode like shown in image below

[image]

**Problem** is when i rotate screen, the `ListView` collapses and displays only one item like shown in image below

[image]

**What** is causing this issue and **how** can i fix it ?

Here's my `xml` layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/randomWordLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfdfdf"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.yousaf.mcqstest.GamePlay"
            android:id="@+id/listViewContainer">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/myListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:dividerHeight="7dp"
                android:padding="10dp">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPoints"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Points : "
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPointsValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCorrectAnswers"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Correct Answers : "
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCorrectAnswersValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textWrongAnswers"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wrong Answers   : "
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textWrongAnswersValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopGame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#222"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There is no place to display all items. How would you have the display to  look like instead?

Comment: i have added a `ScrollView` that would scroll the content that overflows the screen size.

Comment: The last thing you should do is placing a ListView in a ScrollView. Not done! First command!

Comment: @greenapps I know that but if i don't add `ListView` to `ScrollView` then where else should i place it ? `ListView` has to be in middle of the `TextViews` that are currently above and below the `ListView`

Comment: If you want more items of the listview to be displayed you should not display so much other things above and below it. There is a limit to what you can display. Hope you know you can use different layout xml files for portrait and landscape mode. Why not Points, Correct Answers and Wrong answers on one line in landscape mode?

Comment: @greenapps Having different layout for landscape mode and having fixed height of `ListView` in landscape mode fixed this issue. Thankyou for your suggestion of having different layout file for landscape mode.

Comment: You could post a picture of the new landscape!

Comment: posted the picture as well as the steps i did to fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the issue mentioned in my question by having

**1- Separate layout file for landscape mode**. Made a a new folder named `layout-land` inside `res` folder and then copied the layout file included in my question in to `layout-land` folder and then made appropriate changes according to landscape portrait.

**2- Having fixed height for `ListView`**. In my case i set the height of `ListView` to `190dp`.

Now my layout in landscape looks like shown in image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because list view's height is wrap content.

Comment: it displays 4 items in portrait mode with `wrap-content` height.

Comment: `it displays 4 items in portrait mode with wrap-content height` Yes we know. We saw that before on that picture. Why are you repeating the obvious? Why dont you react in a to the point way? Did you change it already?

Comment: @greenapps changing the height of `ListView` to `match-parent` doesn't changes anything

Comment: You should tell that the poster of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `ConstraintLayout`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.yousaf.mcqstest.GamePlay"
            android:id="@+id/listViewContainer"></ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope this will work..

Comment: how is `constraint layout` an issue here ? can you explain ?

Comment: Instead of asking you could just try. And then report.

Comment: @GowthamanM removing constraint layout doesn't changes anything